# split every 50,000 lines and write file in python

Tags: python

I read files which contains 75,151 lines.
I want to split every 50,000 lines.
So I made 2 files, one files have 50,000 lines and the other file has 25,151 lines.

I made code like this
(INSERT_NUMBER : 50,000)

```
 for index, data in enumerate(lines):
   if ((index % INSERT_NUMBER) == 0 and index != 0) or (index == (lines- 1)) : 
           made file ....
```

which is the better way to split every 50,000 lines and make new files ?

Comment: Use [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split). `split --lines=50000 really_big_file.txt`

Comment: @MattDMo is it possible in python?

Comment: Sure - `os.system("split --lines=50000 filename.txt")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out_filename = '/tmp/f{}.txt'
lines_per_file = 50000

with open('infile.txt') as infile:
    for file_number, lines in groupby(enumerate(infile), key=lambda x: x[0] // lines_per_file):
        with open(out_filename.format(file_number), 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(line for line_number, line in lines)
```

So the trick here is to use the line number of each line to group it into chunks using integer division, and then to use the grouping key as a counter for the output file name.

Is it better than what you already have? It's a bit more complicated to read the code, but it doesn't need to deal with those annoying edge cases when you try to group using modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. I try to use it.